# How to kill a process using its name in perl script on windows

Tags: perl, exe

I am running a perl script which calls a batch file.
This batch file runs an exe( It was created by a console application in Visual Studio earlier).

I want to kill this exe from the perl script later using its name.

Could someone please help.

Comment: You could use `ps aux | grep name` to find out processid and then kill it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TASKKILL`, like this:

```
TASKKILL /IM <NAME> /F
```

You'll need to shell out to do it, but you seem to be doing that already to start it anyway.